# What is the time complexity of a log n while loop nested inside a for loop?

Tags: time-complexity, nested-loops

I'm having trouble figuring out the time complexity of the following code.

```
for i in range(0,n):
    x = 1
    while x < n:
        x = x * 2
```

I understand that the outer for loop runs n times, and that the while loop runs log n times (I think). So does that mean because outer for loop has more of an impact so the run time is o(n)?

Answer (score 0):

It's `O(n * log(n))`.

The outer loop is running `n` times and each time it runs it runs the inner loop. The inner loop is indeed `O(log n)`. To see this imagine n being a power of 2. If n is 4,

```
x = 1
while x < n:
   x = x * 2
```

will iterate twice, once when x is 1 and once when x is 2. If n is 8, this loop will iterate 3 times (on x = 1, 2, and 4). Note that 2^2 is four and 2^3 is eight. The number of iterations is the exponent; you could prove this by mathematical induction if you want to be rigorous. We can get that exponent by taking the base-2 log of `n` but by the definition the asymptotic notation we can ignore the base and just say that the loop above runs in `O(log n)` time.

If we have a loop that runs in O(log n) that we are running O(n) times we can say that the whole thing runs in `O(n * log(n))` time.